# Execute docker-compose inside Ansible playbook

Tags: docker-compose, ansible, jinja2

I have an `ansible-playbook.yml` file and from inside I need to execute `docker-compose`:

```yaml
- name: copy sql schema
  hosts: test-mysql
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:        
    - name: Docker compose
      command: docker-compose -f {{ name }}_compose.yml up -d
```

But I always get the error:

```
fatal: [test-mysql]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "docker-compose Mick_compose.yml up -d", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

Any tips?

---

With command:

```yaml
- name: Make sure compose service is up
  docker_compose:
    project_src: /path/to/your/compose/project
    files:
      - {{ name }}_compose.yml
    state: present
```

I get the error:

```
The offending line appears to be:

    - name: Make sure compose service is up
       docker_compose:
                     ^ here
```

Answer (score 3):

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory

There is actually no such file or directory as `Mick_compose.yml` in the default directory where your command is launched. To fix that, I could show you how to change dir from the [command module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html) to the correct one holding your file.

But I will let you discover that on your own (if you still really want to do it after this explanation) because you should not run commands directly when there is an [existing ansible module already doing what you need](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_compose_module.html)

```yaml
- name: Make sure compose service is up
  docker_compose:
    project_src: /path/to/your/compose/project
    files:
      - "{{ name }}_compose.yml"
    state: present
```

This is just to put you on track, have a look at the module doc link above for more info on the possible parameters.

Comment: The offending line appears to be:

        files:
          - {{ name }}-compose.yml
                      ^ here

Comment: It is mandatory to quote your value when it begins with a jinja2 expansion expression, as this was the case in my above example => - `"{{ name }}_compose.yml"`

Answer (score 1):

Directory where playbook runs doesn't contain the `{{ name }}_compose.yml` file.

There's [relevant module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_compose_module.html) which can help you.
If you don't want to use it, you can add task which will show the directory where playbook runs:

```
- name: copy sql schema
  hosts: test-mysql
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
    - name: Docker compose
      command: docker-compose -f {{ name }}_compose.yml up -d
```

Then, either move `{{ name }}_compose.yml` to the directory or provide an absolute path in command: `docker-compose -f [abs_path]{{ name }}_compose.yml up -d`